# "Cannot remove an observer" or "An instance of class was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it" errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So, I writing a game on cocos2d framework. I got a rocket flying through space and I need to stop everything when pause buttons was touched. In because of this I make an observer in base `GameObject` class which saying:

`[[Game sharedGame] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isPaused" options:0 context:nil];`

in `init` method and

`[[Game sharedGame] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isPaused"];`

in `dealloc` method

So, I got an error saying `Cannot remove an observer <Rocket 0xa3a1c10> for the key path "isPaused" from <Game 0x94a7cc0> because it is not registered as an observer.`
when I try to restart scene. And if I try this with try catch, its not calling an exception but still not work correctly, giving me a message

`An instance 0xb1d3380 of class Game was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x13c6fa20> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0xb1b6740: Observer: 0xb120ce0, Key path: isPaused, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0xb1171a0>`

and blah-blah-blah

what should I do?

Regards.

Comment: it seems, that you don't delete your game objects correctly. check it with leaks instrument

Comment: it looks more like objects change their links while the transition finished. I got memory warnings only if I use "try catch" instruction, it means that I got error messages, but ignoring. I change position of `removeObserver` method from `dealloc` to `onExit`. But sadly its not even give any changes

Comment: i mean that from your error messages it seems that game singleton object ( [Game sharedGame] ) was deleted before your rockets. so to the moment of their dealloc there is no object to remove them from observers.

Comment: So yep, it seems to be right. I checked links on instance and they were different. So, how can I save needed instance? I tried to save it into variable but it makes no sence.

Comment: I suspect that your `[Game sharedGame]` is not actually a singleton. Post code of `sharedGame` method, please.